# How is this binary tree algorithm's conditional statement working?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am looking at the implementation of an algorithm proposed at [Build the binary search tree from inorder and preorder traversals](http://algorithmsandme.blogspot.com/2013/10/binary-search-tree-build-binary-search.html#.VNDg4GjF_oK).

I think the implementation is in c++ and I have a question about this one line `Node * temp =  (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));` and the evaluation of its following `if` condition as seen in a block like this :

```
Node * temp =  (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
if(temp){
    //do some stuff
    //conditionally return a Node
}
return NULL
```

Node is presumably a binary tree node. Its implementation is not shown, but how is that `if(temp)` condition working such that the last `return NULL` is ever reached?

Comment: *"I think the implementation is in c++"*.  It's in C.

Comment: `return` _is_ reached. `if(temp)` here is shorthand for `if(temp != NULL)`.

Comment: ok, so it's returning pointers, and that's what sizeof(Node) evaluates - null pointers return what in that case?

Comment: @ThisClark in a Boolean context, a `NULL` pointer is false, and a non-`NULL` pointer (i. e. anything else) is true.

Comment: Also, the cast to `(Node *)` is [superfluous and harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858). That site doesn't seem to be a very professional resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(temp)` means `if (temp!=NULL)`, which essentially means that if the Node* temp was successfully malloc'ed and returned from malloc, then enter the `if` block of code.  Unless there is code to return something in the `if` block (which would then exit the program), the `return NULL` statement will execute.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional in an `if` is considered *false* if it evaluates to `0`, and *true* if it's non-zero.

> how is that `if(temp)` condition working such that the last `return NULL` is ever reached?

It's reached if `temp` is `NULL`, which evaluates to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

the `if` block is executed whenever the condition statement (which is `temp` in your case) is not equal to zero. In C the `NULL` pointer has a numerical value of zero. So if `temp` is `NULL`, the `if` block will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

In C prior to C99, there wass no specially designated boolean type. A *scalar type* was, and still can be used instead, such as `int` or a pointer like, in your case, `Node*`. A zero value is equivalent to `false`, a nonzero value is equivalent to `true`.

So, in your example, the pointer `temp` is the condition in the `if` statement. That means that the code in the `if` will execute if the value of `temp` is `true`, i.e. doesn't equal zero (`NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code structure should be,

```
Node * temp =  (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
if( temp != NULL ){
    //do some stuff
    //conditionally return a Node
}
else
{
    return NULL;
}
```

you should not follow the structure you shown for code readability.